# android app runs perfectly on device but always force close on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-2.2-froyo

I have an app in progress that includes shaders for Android 2.2. When I install the app on my HTC Desire it runs perfectly but when I run it from (the correct emulator with GPU enabled) the app always force closes and I do not understand why. I do not know how to find the issue or where to find some extra information to give you. If some is needed let me know. The app is a rendering grass shader (currently only have 2 triangles setup). But I have GPU emulation enabled on the VD

```
11-19 19:53:27.291: D/libEGL(274): egl.cfg not found, using default config
11-19 19:53:27.291: D/libEGL(274): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
11-19 19:53:27.321: W/dalvikvm(274): threadid=7: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
11-19 19:53:27.361: E/AndroidRuntime(274): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 8
11-19 19:53:27.361: E/AndroidRuntime(274): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No configs match configSpec
11-19 19:53:27.361: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$BaseConfigChooser.chooseConfig(GLSurfaceView.java:760)
11-19 19:53:27.361: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:916)
11-19 19:53:27.361: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1246)
11-19 19:53:27.361: E/AndroidRuntime(274):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1116)
11-19 19:53:29.841: I/Process(274): Sending signal. PID: 274 SIG: 9
```

Comment: see the LogCat, Luke... Always check logs at first....

Comment: run adb logcat from the terminal and post the error log

Comment: I am using eclipse on windows. Please explain more on how to

Comment: Eclipse> window > showView > LogCat.  Get the error logs when the app crashes and post the logs here!

Comment: thank you sir, I will run it again now and edit my post

Comment: all messages no filters or only the app specific messages??

Comment: added, thanks for the guidance on how to find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems. Even though GPU emulation is something that can be turned on, OpenGL ES is not something that can run on an emulator. It is (as of the time of this answer) impossible to execute a shader in an emulator so an app with shaders cannot run on an emulator

**Update:**
OpenGL ES 2.0 [is supported in the emulator](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/04/faster-emulator-with-better-hardware.html) from Android 4 onwards, when Host GPU option is turned on.

Comment: Note that OpenGL ES 2.0 *is* supported in the emulator from Android 4 onwards, when `Host GPU` option is turned on.

Comment: @HRJ Yes but I was using android 2.2 still dont understand why my question was closed

Answer (score 1):

Are you using camera? Seems similar to this one:

[" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No configs match configSpec " While opening Camera Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594636/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-no-configs-match-configspec-while-openin)

Camera is not support in Android emulator so don't worry about it.

If you are trying to run OpenGL, also not supported by the amulator.

Please tell us what kind of app you are working on!

Comment: no I am not, I am simply trying to create a shader (currently only have two triangles) and I have gpu emulation enabled

Comment: I have no experience with OpenGl, but it seems difficult to make it work in the emulator... Cannot help you more, tahn wjat I already did. sorry