# OpenGL ES Application on Android Emulator with GPU disabled (Software Accelerated)

Tags: android, opengl-es, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I'm trying to run an Android OpenGL ES application on the Raspberry Pi 2 (Android Lollipop 5.1). There is no support for Hardware Acceleration at the moment, so I have do all the rendering in software.

The same environment of the R Pi can be recreated on an Emulator (AVD) with the following configuration: ARMv7, GPU disabled and Android 5.1.

If I enable the GPU in the Emulator, everything works fine, but if I disable it, I get the following error:

```
10-23 22:53:36.798    1550-1565/com.example.android.mediaeffects E/AndroidRuntime﹕ 
FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 187
Process: com.example.android.mediaeffects, PID: 1550
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No configs match configSpec
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$BaseConfigChooser.chooseConfig(GLSurfaceView.java:858)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:1023)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1400)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1239)
```

I saw that this error has been also common for other people, like this post:

[" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No configs match configSpec " While opening Camera Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594636/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-no-configs-match-configspec-while-openin)

or in this other post:

[OpenGL ES 2.0 Support for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717470/opengl-es-2-0-support-for-android)

The solutions that are working for other people are:

1) Enabling GPU on Emulator

2) Setting the EGL configuration in the following way:

```
setEGLConfigChooser(8 , 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
```

My problem is that I needs the GPU to be disabled (since on the R Pi it's disabled), so I still keep to get this error.

I'm also forcing Software Acceleration on the Manifest file by adding the following:

```
<application
    .....
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    .....>
```

but this doesn't seem to change anything.

Does anyone has any idea of how to solve this issue, but still working with the GPU disabled and with Software Acceleration (hardwareAccelerated="false")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by using the following `setEGLConfigChooser()` method implementation:

```
mEffectView = (GLSurfaceView) view.findViewById(R.id.effectsview);
mEffectView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
mEffectView.setEGLConfigChooser(new GLSurfaceView.EGLConfigChooser() {
        @Override
        public EGLConfig chooseConfig(EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display) {
            /* Get the number of minimally matching EGL configurations  */
              int[] s_configAttribs2 =
                    {
                            EGL10.EGL_RED_SIZE, 4,
                            EGL10.EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 4,
                            EGL10.EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 4,
                            EGL10.EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, 1,
                            EGL10.EGL_NONE
                    };

            int[] num_config = new int[1];
            egl.eglChooseConfig(display, s_configAttribs2, null, 0, num_config);

            int numConfigs = num_config[0];

            if (numConfigs <= 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("No configs match configSpec");
            }

        /* Allocate then read the array of minimally matching EGL configs */
            EGLConfig[] configs = new EGLConfig[numConfigs];
            egl.eglChooseConfig(display, s_configAttribs2, configs, numConfigs, num_config);


        /* Return the first configuration found */
            return configs[0];
        }
    });
```

Using this method a valid EGL configuration is correctly found.

The function code has been derived from: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/14b0a6bc0ec8814291751b2b8e80da606cfa12b3/core/java/android/view/HardwareRenderer.java